# Developing the save function in Gutenberg blocks

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, block-editor

I am editing the `save` function on my local wordpress instance. Every time I make a change, I need to manually click the "Attempt Block Recovery" button to see the updated change when I go to preview a page.

Is there a way to automatically invoke this without needing this extra step of clicking a button?

so for example if my save function looks like this

```
save: function() {
        return <div className='test'>test</div>;
}
```

and I update it to be the following

```
save: function() {
    return <div className='test2'>testing again</div>;
}
```

I cannot see these changes unless I go to the block editor, resolve the block recovery, click update, and then refresh the preview page again.

I would ideally just like to be able to refresh the page to see the changes.

Comment: You could use the [`deprecated` property](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-deprecation/), but it seems like you might better off change your block to a [dynamic block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/) which skips the [block validation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/#validation-faq) and saves you from those hassles in question..